# Circular csv feeder giving IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using a feeder to plug in values in a request body.

`val feeder = csv("feeders/project_tenants.csv").circular`

```
def updateDbSettings = feed(feeder)
    exec(http("Update Project Settings")
    .post("/url/here")
    .body(StringBody("""{"sqlServer":"${server}.test.int","sqlDatabase":"COMP_DB", "dataCenter":"HAI"}""")).asJson)
```

My csv file looks like this

```
server,test
check,a
check1,b
check2,c
check3,d
```

Each time I run the test I'm getting `IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine` exception which I don't understand because my feeder is circular. I understand that should mean the values will iterate over again once reaching the end of the file. But even if I load only one session I get that error.

Stacktrace with a single user per one second:

```
14:18:39.076 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
        at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:67)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
[ERROR] [07/25/2022 14:18:39.118] [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(GatlingSystem)] ex        at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:67)
ception while executing timer task
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.system(BaseActor.scala:27)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at io.gatling.graphite.sender.TcpSender.askForConnection(TcpSender.scala:103)
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:25)
        at io.gatling.graphite.sender.TcpSender$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(TcpSender.scala:58)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:202)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:343)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.$anonfun$close$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:145)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.$anonfun$close$1$adapted(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:144)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.close(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:144)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.stopScheduler(ActorSystem.scala:980)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.$anonfun$_start$1(ActorSystem.scala:910)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anon$2.run(ActorSystem.scala:931)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$TerminationCallbacks$$anonfun$addRec$1$1.applyOrElse(ActorSystem.scala:1118)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$TerminationCallbacks$$anonfun$addRec$1$1.applyOrElse(ActorSystem.scala:1118)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:49)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: You should try to come up with a reproducer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So it turned out to be a couple of things. After adding a new csv file and entering values, I still had to rebuild my project in order for the values/attributes to be recognized. After that I realized I also hadn't added a `.` before the `exec` as seen in the code block above in my post. Thanks @StéphaneLANDELLE for acknowledging my post anyway. Having fun learning gatling :)